# Frequency significantly different from zero

Tags: statistical-significance, chi-squared-test

I've got a few frequencies, and I'm trying to work out if each of the frequencies is significantly different from zero. Most of the frequencies I can eyeball, but I wanted to have some for of statistic for some of the other frequencies.

Does anybody know of an appropriate statistical test for this? I couldn't seem to get SPSS or SAS to do this with Chi-square.

I've seen similar 'significantly different from zero' tests for continuous or ordered-categorical data but haven't found anything for frequencies.

Any ideas?

Simon.

Answer (score 3):

Note that if a population proportion is 0, you can't observe *any* counts in that category.

As a result you can always use this rejection rule:

> *If a sample count is not 0, reject the hypothesis that the population frequency is 0.*

This test has type I error rate of 0 (there are no false rejections, since you can never reject unless the population frequency is non-zero). Power depends on sample size and the underlying frequency.